# CSS Hero Image height issue

Tags: css

I use the following code to display like a stretchy responsive banner image on my website, I've got the code from another site (https://www.svenskakyrkan.se/onsala/adventsmusik) where it works as expected.

```css
.hero {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.hero .hero-image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero .hero-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 240px;
  max-height: 800px;
  background: center center #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.hero .hero-image:after {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-image-container">

    <figure class="hero-image" style="background-image: url('/images/banner.jpg'); max-height: 504px;"></figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is the image is only 240 pixels tall, so height auto isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the pseudo-element content and make it `display:block`:

```css
.hero {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.hero .hero-image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero .hero-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 240px;
  max-height: 800px;
  background: center center #fff;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.hero .hero-image:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-image-container">

    <figure class="hero-image" style="background-image: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/1000/500'); max-height: 504px;"></figure>
  </div>
</div>
```